# Adjective for "pertaining to traffic"

Tags: single-word-requests

I've trying to specify the "body" language we use while stuck in traffic. I'm hoping for a word ending in -al.

At work we use professional body language, at home we use social body language, while stuck in traffic we use _______ body language.

At first I thought "automotive" or "vehicular." I think this conveys a sense of being in a car, but without the context of being on the road with other cars, jostling for position. To convey the interactive component, I thought maybe "vehiculo-social" but it's a bit contrived, and still leaves out that we are moving slowly on a crowded road rather than zipping down the freeway doing 80mph. "Traffical" just sounds silly.

So is there a word for this? Am I stuck with "vehicular"?

Comment: Can you use _jockeying_ body language?

Comment: Technically I guess I should wait awhile to make sure nobody comes up with an answer, but I'm pretty certain there is no word for this. You could invent one, if it is important enough and you're writing the kind of document where it is appropriate to invent words. It might be helpful to know what body language this is exactly - by which I mean, is there really a set of body language we consistently use in traffic jams and consistently don't use outside of traffic jams? Or is the body language you're thinking of something that exists in other situations, and could thus involve different words?

Comment: For example I notice that you associate "home" with "social" body language, even though this doesn't seem a good fit to me (I won't use the same body language if I'm alone at home vs if I'm with family at home, or with friends at home, and I wouldn't describe all of those situations as "social"), yet your objection to using "vehicular" for "traffic-related" is that the fit isn't perfect. There is certainly a reason why you use these words, but it isn't completely clear what your process is from your question and it might help if it were clearer what you need from the word you're asking for.

Comment: @RozennKeribin By "social," I was thinking at home with friends and other people with whom you are close, as opposed to a professional setting with people who are not close.  I think you may be right, there is not word for this becasue I'm trying to cram two things into one word: in a car, and in slow traffic.  Yosef may have the best answer for this.

Comment: I don't think there is unique body language for being in a car in traffic.  Body language reflects subconscious things that relate to emotional states.  People react to different aspects of traffic and react in different ways.  For example, body language could reflect stress or aggression.  You would do better to look for a word that reflects the specifics of the situation and the person's reaction to it.

Comment: The usage 'body language" in any of these situations as assumed by you seems wrong. e.g. there is no such thing as "I use professional body language". I have seen body language being used in contexts that denote a frame of mind. e.g. "he seemed to be very angry from his body language" or "your body language conveys whether you are interested in what the other person is saying" etc. Hope this helps.

Comment: I wonder if you really mean body language  - a driver's body language is going to reflect their mood  and attitude rather than whether they're driving. Think of gritted teeth and clenched fists while stuck  in traffic on the way to an appointment, compared to someone on the same queue who's not in a hurry. I would say there's  a set  of gestures associated with driving

Comment: If a driver is trying to convey meaning to other drivers, then they use gestural body language, e.g. "He gesticulated wildly at the other driver who had just carved him up". If a driver is driving calmly, then their posture might reflect that. If they're impatient, they might tap their foot (not on the accelerator, one hopes). I'd also dispute the idea of professional body language being a different set of postures & gestures  - it's more of a subset of social body language.